# How can I tell cppcheck to ignore inline assembly?

Tags: inline-assembly, cppcheck

We have a file within inline assembly for a DSP.  Cppcheck thinks there are a load of "variable assigned but not used" lines in the assembly.

Is there any way to tell it to skip checking the inline assembly sections?  I couldn't see anything obvious in the manual, and it is a bit tedious to have to suppress each line in turn (t

Here's an example of some of the the offending lines.  It's a context save routine.

```
inline assembly void save_ctx()
{
asm_begin
.undef global data saved_ctx; 
.undef global data p_ctx;  
asm_text
    ...
    st XM[p0++], r0;
    st XM[p0++], r1;    
    st XM[p0++], r2;    
    st XM[p0++], r3;    
    st XM[p0++], r4;    
    st XM[p0++], r5;    
    st XM[p0++], r6;   
    ...
```

I can turn off the messages with
// cppcheck-suppress unreadVariable
before each line, but it would be better to just tell cppcheck to skip the whole inline assembly section.

Is there any way I can do this, or will we just have to accept lots of repeated comments?

Comment: Seems like you should be able to use `-D` or `-U`.  If you wrap your asm in `#ifndef cppcheck`, then I'd expect `-Dcppcheck` to skip it.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd thank you. Obvious really - couldn't see the wood for the trees.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Somewhat counter-intuitive, but thanks to @DavidWohlferd for pointing me the right way.

`-D__CPPCHECK__` *doesn't* do the right thing.  It tells cppcheck to *only* check blocks with `__CPPCHECK__` or nothing defined, i.e. it completely turns off the combinatorial checking.  However there is a simple but counter-intuitive solution using -U.

Wrap the block with

```
#define EXCLUDE_CPPCHECK
#ifdef EXCLUDE_CPPCHECK
...
#endif  // EXCLUDE_CPPCHECK
```

Now if you call cppcheck with `-UEXCLUDE_CPPCHECK` it will skip that block (even though the #define is just before it!) but still do all the other combinations of #define which are used in #if.

Thank you David and Drew.

Comment: Having never used cppcheck, I was just guessing.  But it seemed reasonable.  That said, I'm surprised cppcheck doesn't have a symbol that it 'predefines' for just this purpose.

Comment: This helped me mark (and bisect) a block of code that was making cppcheck crash. The alternatives didn't help with this particular problem. `-U` option was a life saver. It is not even well documented https://cppcheck.sourceforge.io/manual.pdf.

Comment: The alternative with `-D` would be `#ifdef WITH_ASM` or something, and you `-DWITH_ASM` in your normal builds but not with cppcheck.  That's probably less nice, because it means you need extra options for the code to be usable.  Unless you do `#ifndef __CPPCHECK__` / `#define WITH_ASM` / `#endif` in some header everything includes, then you can *just* have standard #ifdef / #endif fences without the distraction of a #define right in front.  (@alfC)

Comment: @PeterCordes, thank you. For bisecting code (I had no alternative), doing `#define EXCLUDE_CPPCHECK` at the top of the file (that I knew was problematic), `-UEXCLUDE_CPPCHECK` in the `cppcheck` command like (passed through cmake) and `#ifdef EXCLUDE_CPPCHECK` / `#endif` around the offending code (e.g. a very large class) was enough for me without interfering with the options for normal compilation.

Answer (score 2):

According to man page (didn't try myself) you can add command line options:

```
--suppress=<spec>
```

> Suppress a specific warning. The format of `<spec>` is: `[error id]:[filename]:[line]`. The `[filename]` and `[line]` are optional. `[error id]` may be `*` to suppress all warnings (for a specified file or files). `[filename]` may contain the wildcard characters `*` or `?`.

```
--suppressions-list=<file>
```

> Suppress warnings listed in the file. Each suppression is in the format of `<spec>` above.

I.e. in your case `--suppress=unreadVariable:all_dsp_asm_*.cpp` and switch it completely for those particular files. Which is IMO usable, as you can put all the DSP inline asm things into separate file, so it will not affect your ordinary cpp check.

Or in worst case use the suppression-list listing file, where you may list particular lines ad absurd I guess, to cover whole inline parts.

I don't see how to inline it in the source, looks like it may affect only single line.

---

Checking probably more up to date version of [manual here](http://cppcheck.sourceforge.net/manual.pdf), you can exclude whole file also by `-i<filename>` (second page).

The options above are at page 11.

Comment: I thought about that but unfortunately it doesn't work for me.  I don't want to completely disable the check for that file, only for the inline assembly section.